# Nativescript: How to get all images from gallery?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, typescript

Are there any opportunity get access to gallery, take list of photos and use them in an application? Of course if are is it possible to filter them by criteria (get photos by date range)?

Comment: Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes.

Comment: how to do it???

Comment: You are #12345 asking this. There are many tutorials on the internet and many examples on this site. Google.

Comment: Please, see it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514494/nativescript-how-to-get-photo-list-from-gallery

Comment: Nobody answered as all is so obvious. Everyone will conclude that you are too lazy to google.

Comment: You are too lazy to answer. If I found I would not ask

Comment: Just google for how to make a gallery and you find all code.

Comment: I googled and found nothing on nativescript and gallery

Answer (score 0):

GingerComa, I supposed you want to user choose the images from gallery, right? I get this done with this nativescript plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-imagepicker

```
import * as imagepicker from "nativescript-imagepicker";

let context = imagepicker.create({
    mode: "single" // use "multiple" for multiple selection
});

context
    .authorize()
    .then(function() {
        return context.present();
    })
    .then(function(selection) {
        selection.forEach(function(selected) {
            // process the selected image
        });
        list.items = selection;
    }).catch(function (e) {
        // process error
    });
```